# HTML Navigation Bar extend to bottom

Tags: html, css

I created a navigation bar for my school project (I'm doing basic design, then we're adding the mysql database), and the bar works great, but it does not extend to the bottom of the page, it's just a little box right now.

Here's my style script

```
style type='text/css'>
#navigation {
 display:block;
 width:150px;
 float:left;
 margin-left:7px;
 margin-right6px;
 margin:5px;
 border-style:solid;
}
#navhead {
 text-align:center;
 margin-left:7px;
 margin-right:6px;
}
#links {
 display:block;
 width:60px;
}
</style>
```

Am I missing any attributes that say 'extend to bottom of frame?'

Thanks!

Comment: Please use jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com with your HTML and CSS to help us helping you.

Comment: use jsfiddle to show us what it looks like in browser..

Comment: I don't know what those are, but here's the link to the project being hosted on my schools site. https://php.radford.edu/~jalexander/itec325/project/index.php

Comment: If you don't put all of the relevant code directly into this question, then it isn't useful to anyone else.

Comment: That was pretty relevant -- Calvein answered it perfectly: it was a height:100%; that I was missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `height` property. You can set the `height` to 100% (the height of this parent, so the `<body>`) but it will looks weird, because it will render the height + the padding + border + margin.
You need to use the [`border-box`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing) property with the height. It allows you to define if the padding and/or border (or none, by default) are count in the `height` and `width` properties. You also needs to kill the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom`.
After those changes, here what your CSS should look like :

```
#navigation {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```